# Kernel updates don't install some packages on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

Whenever a kernel update is available through apt update the following packages do not get installed:

(these from the latest kernel upgrade)

- linux-headers-5.8.0-40-generic
- linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-40
- linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-40-generic

I have to install them manually.

This may be related to the first kernel update to my system failing part way through because the keyutils package was not installed and I have encrypted disks. I had to manually install the missing packages.

This is a fresh install of ubuntu not and upgrade

Comment: You are correct. This happened because there was a failure in the process of package upgrades.

Comment: Is `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 ` installed?

Comment: Nope linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 is not installed?

Comment: So this is the reason.

Comment: Superb thanks hopfully that will fix the problem

Comment: See the answer. It will fix the problem. I guess you removed some kernel packages manually that removed the meta ones.

Answer (score 5):

These packages are dependencies of `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` and `linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` [meta packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/linux-meta-hwe-5.8).

It is hard to tell why they are not installed, but you can fix the issue by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

It should install both meta packages.